# Sum of the squared sums OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to sum all the squared sums of two consecutive elements from a float list by using my foldl function.

```
let rec foldl (f: 'b -> 'a -> 'b) (accum: 'b) (lst: 'a list) : 'b = match lst with 
|[] -> accum
|x::xs -> foldl f (f accum x) xs 

let sum_sqrt_sums (mylist:  float list) : float = match mylist with
 |[] -> raise(Failure "Nope")
 |[x] -> raise(Failure "No!")
 |x::xs -> foldl (fun x y -> sqrt (x +. y)) x xs
```

I have two different results when I run

```
sum_sqrt_sums [4.0; 2.0; 6.0; 3.0];;
- : float = 2.43039103901312092

sqrt(4.0 +. 2.0) +. sqrt(2.0 +. 6.0) +. sqrt(6.0 +. 3.0) ;;
- : float = 8.27791686752936862
```

What is wrong with my logic in my sum function?

Comment: `fold f a [x1; .. ; xn] = f ( .. (f (f a x1) x2) .. ) xn`.  Try expand `foldl (fun x y -> sqrt (x +. y)) 4.0 [2.0; 6.0; 3.0]` by hand, then you will find it is something different what you want to implement.

Comment: @RichouHunter What is your thought on this?

Comment: @camlspotter yeah I wrote it down on paper a while ago and I spotted out the error. Still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I would first write a function that transforms the initial list into a list of consecutive tuples : [(4.0,2.0);(2.0,6.0);(6.0,3.0)]. and then apply a fold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function `sum_sqrt_sums` doesn't compute

```
sqrt(4.0 +. 2.0) +. sqrt(2.0 +. 6.0) +. sqrt(6.0 +. 3.0)
```

but

```
sqrt (sqrt (sqrt(2.0 +. 4.0) +. 6.0) +. 3.0)
```

What you want to do is to keep the last element seen in the accumulator to add it to the next one and add the squared sum of them to the accumulator :

```
let sum_sqrt_sums = function
  | [] | [_] -> raise(Failure "Nope")
  | x::xs -> 
     let _, res = foldl (fun (x, acc) y -> (y, sqrt (x +. y) +. acc)) (x, 0.) xs in
     res
```

(*as a side note, your* `foldl` *function is the* `List.fold_left` *function*)

---

Update (version with a different variable name to avoid confusion) :

```
let sum_sqrt_sums = function
  | [] | [_] -> raise(Failure "Nope")
  | x::xs -> 
     let _, res = foldl (fun (e, acc) y -> (y, sqrt (e +. y) +. acc)) (x, 0.) xs in
     res
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me what "_,res" means? I cannot wrap my head around this structure. Thank you.

Comment: It's just that I don't need the first member of the tuple so I don't name it when I destroy the tuple. I could write `let x, res = ...` but I won't use `x` so I don't need to name it. As an example, if I write `let a, b = (2, 3)` I will have `a <- 2` and `b <- 3` but if I write `let _, b = (2, 3)`, `b <- 3` and no variable will be bounded to 2. (I don't put the parentheses but `let _, res` is the same as `let (_, res)`).

Comment: So can I say that the foldl function returns a tuple in the format of (_,res)? Or can I say that foldl function will return the same type as (fun (x,acc) y) returns?

Comment: `foldl` will indeed return the same type as `fun (x, acc) y -> ...` returns but I don't see where you would want to say that it returns a tuple in the format of `(_, res)`.

Comment: I said that because when I see "let (_,res) = foldl ...", I always think that oh foldl returns a tuple. Am I right?

Comment: Also, in fun (x, acc) y -> (x, sqrt (x +. y) +. acc)) (x, 0.), is x here the same x in x::xs?

Comment: Oh, yes, exactly, when you see `let _, res = foldl` it means that `foldl` returns a tuple. For your other comment, no, since I wrote `(fun (x, acc) y -> ...) (x, 0.)` every `x` appearing in `...` will be the one declared in `fun (x, acc)` but since `(x, 0.)` is not in the block opened by `fun ...`, this `x` is the one from `x :: xs`.

Comment: I updated my answer and fixed a mistake I made in `| [] | [x]` which is not allowed because `x` is bounded in the second branch but not in the first one so I have to write `| [] | [_]`.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how this works. For example, I want to compute: sum_sqrt_sums [4.0; 2.0; 6.0; 3.0]. I understand I start with (4.0, 0.0). Then fun (e, acc) y -> (e, sqrt (e +. y) +. acc) is applied and it requires two elements: a tuple and a float. So does y come from xs?

Comment: Yep because I apply your `foldl` to `xs`. And I just noticed another mistake I made (never answer when you just woke up) : when you create the new accumulator, you have to give it `y`, not `e`.

Answer (score 1):

`to_tuple` : converts a list to a list of tuples

```
let rec to_tuple aux l = match l with
| [] -> aux | [x] -> aux
| a::(b::tl as ll) -> to_tuple ((a,b)::aux) ll;;

to_tuple [] [4.0; 2.0; 6.0; 3.0];;
- : (float * float) list = [(6., 3.); (2., 6.); (4., 2.)]
```

And final step:

```
List.fold_left (fun acc (x,y) -> acc+. sqrt (x+.y)) 0. [(6., 3.); (2., 6.); (4., 2.)];;
```